# Python pytesseract problem to open '[Errno 13] Permission denied:' in Mac

Tags: python, macos, permissions

I am having trouble with pytesseract in python. When I call the file in the code it says permission is denied. I am working on Mac, so I do not know what to do but I hope you can help me.

```
#from every single image-based cell/box the strings are extracted via pytesseract and stored in a list
outer=[]
for i in range(len(finalboxes)):
    for j in range(len(finalboxes[i])):
        inner=''
        if(len(finalboxes[i][j])==0):
            outer.append(' ')
        else:
            for k in range(len(finalboxes[i][j])):
                y,x,w,h = finalboxes[i][j][k][0],finalboxes[i][j][k][1], finalboxes[i][j][k][2],finalboxes[i][j][k][3]
                finalimg = bitnot[x:x+h, y:y+w]
                kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 1))
                border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(finalimg,2,2,2,2,   cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[255,255])
                resizing = cv2.resize(border, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                dilation = cv2.dilate(resizing, kernel,iterations=1)
                erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel,iterations=1)

                
                out = pytesseract.image_to_string(erosion) # This line is the one that gives the error
                if(len(out)==0):
                    out = pytesseract.image_to_string(erosion, config='--psm 3')
                inner = inner +" "+ out
            outer.append(inner)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an assignment to pytesseract of the executable file for tesseract?
Since I don't see it in your code, I will assume you are not. I will also assume that you used Homebrew to install tesseract OCR. If you used macports or are using on another os, check official [install documentation here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html).
Your entire script should at least contain the following:

1. An import of the pytesseract module.

`import pytesseract`

2. An assignment to the pytesseract module instance of the tesseract executable. This must refer to the path and the tesseract executable binary for it to function adequately:

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/[version]/bin/tesseract'`

3. You may now call upon any method of the pytesseract methods, for example:

`print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'/Path/to/image/you/want/to/process/Picture1.png'))`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You were right, I needed to install it from Homebrew, I am new in Mac.

It was not in the path so used this line to install it correctly.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was using which and then used that path:

```
which tesseract
```

the path it brings back is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users, Please execute **Which Tesseract** in terminal which will provide you the Tesseract executable path. This resolved the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).